# Wordpress menu, refresh only content

Tags: wordpress, animation, navigation, interactive

I am sitting with my final study project and i am trying to build a page with the navigation links working as animation triggers.

Each page has its own animation on entering and exiting, but how can I make the wordpress menu change only the content without refreshing the footer, header and menu?

I am using a custom theme, based on Bones

In case I explained it weirdly. Instead of scrolling to a certain point on clicking the nav, the shown page' exit animation will start, and the wanted page' entering animation will start shortly after

Comment: learn jQuery, its called interacting with the dom if you want to make changes without page refresh.

Comment: Does it have to be WordPress? Sounds like something that would be better off custom-coded.

Comment: it is a requirement to be wordpress yes. Unfortunately. 
So as far as i have figured out, i will need a function to rewrite the wordpress generated nav to something like <a id="menu-title">menu-title</a> and leave out the href, or smth. And then add the rules through jQuery to the specific a id's.